# How to use the Button I created via Netbeans GUI builder in my main class?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I used the Netbeans feature to create a GUI component on an **existing project** (Right clicking the package > new > Jframe 
called it GuInterface.

I created my buttons and added what the click should do, but I have no idea how to actually implement it in my main class. I tried calling `GuInterface.jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` from my main, but it doesn't recognize it as a valid statement.

How to actually call the method in main?

Main class:
    public class TorreHanoiRecursion {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) { 


       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setVisible(true);



    }
```

I just want to call the button I created via Netbeans in that main class.

Comment: You don't - or shouldn't.  Create an instance of the (`JFrame`) class and show it, from there, when a button is clicked, the linked action methods will be called

Comment: I'm not really getting that. I created a new JFrame in my main code and put frame.setVisible(true); but then what? It only opens a blank window. How do I actually link it to the button I created?

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Check the code that NetBeans generated. It's likely that the GuInterface class extends JFrame. If that's the case then you probably want to replace `new JFrame()` with `new GuInterface()`

Comment: Thank you. Yes the issue was that I had to create an instance of the class created, I was creating an actual JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

From the pop-up menu choose Events --> Action --> ActionPerformed. Note that the menu contains many more events you can respond to! When you select the actionPerformed event, the IDE will automatically add an ActionListener to the button and generate a handler method for handling the listener's actionPerformed method.

The IDE will open up the Source Code window and scroll to where you implement the action you want the button to do when the button is pressed (either by mouse click or via keyboard). Your Source Code window should contain the following lines:

private void jButton3ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

{

//TODO: Add your handling code here:

}